# Cast sql.ColumnName to Double

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, casting

I need to call scala.math.pow to calulate a number, but I'm having issues casting a column created in scala sql and cast to a double.

This is the line I use to call the power function.

```
scala.math.pow(pr,$”numinLinks”)
```

I have a spark sql data frame that has a column that I attempted to cast to a double using this UDL.

```
val toDouble = udf[Double, Int]( _.toDouble)
```

Then I called this on my data frame.

```
val joinDFAdjusted = join.withColumn(“numInLinks”, toDouble(joinDF(“numInLinks”)))
```

In the schema, it shows that my column is of StructField(numInLinks, Double, true). This is the error I receive.

```
found: org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName
required: Double
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `pow` function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.pow

join.withColumn("numInLinksExp", pow($"pr", $"numinLinks"))
```

Comment: Here is more context of the code segment. I need to call the pow function on each item. The pr variable will change depending on that row. A global change on the column will not work.

Comment: val result = joinDFAdjusted.select($"p1_main”, $"p2_main”, (($”numInLinks" / $"totalInLinks”) * ($”numOutLinks" / $"totalOutLinks”)) * (scala.math.pow(pr,$”numinLinks”)))